# fetching the days using numpy datetime?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>> np.datetime64('2012')+np.timedelta64(20,'D')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: function takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Recently i used this snippet in my program and unfortunately i got an exception which is not supposed to have happened according to the below doc

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: I belive the 'D' is causing the problem.

Comment: 'D' is an accepted argument according to the doc

Comment: Have you looked at [this?](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?t=30380&p=142307)

Answer (score 2):

np.timedelta64 only takes one argument in earlier versions of Numpy (e.g. 1.6). This is the timedelta in milliseconds.

It's only since version 1.7 that it takes the second argument.

See this discussion: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.user/30459